# Разная скорость работы python скрипта на идентичных серверах

Tags: linux, python-3.x, centos, время, centos7

Столкнулся с проблемой: есть маленький скрипт python (по переводу PDF в JPG). На вход подается PDF файл, на выходе из него формируются JPG изображения. Этот скрипт необходимо запускать на двух разных серверах. И на одном скорость исполнения скрипта в два раза быстрее, чем на втором (на одном real time 28s, sys time 0.7s, на втором real time 50s, sys time 1.7s), при попытке обработать один и тот же PDF. На более быстром сервере установлен CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core), на более медленном CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core). 
Интерпретатор на быстром Python 3.6.5, на медленном Python 3.6.6. Характеристики серверов идентичные. Объем свободной оперативной памяти тоже почти не отличается.
Библиотеки используются только OS, SYS и Wand. Версии Wand идентичны 0.5.1.
На что еще можно обратить внимание, чтобы понять причину?

Comment: `user time` также отличается? вручную конвертировать ImageMagick'ом пробовал? скорости сравнивал? чем-то ещё сервера нагружены? железо на серверах сравнимо?

Comment: Надо прогнать скрипт под профайлером на обоих серверах и сравнивать результаты профилирования.

Comment: Прогнал скрипт с профайлером cProfile и получил следующие данные: 
 на быст
 ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno
        1   25.503   25.503   25.503   25.503 image.py:4845(read)
        1    2.184    2.184    2.184    2.184 image.py:4898(save)
 на медл
 ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno
        1   47.202   47.202   47.202   47.202 image.py:4845(read)
        1    4.082    4.082    4.082    4.082 image.py:4898(save)
Измерил скорость чтения в hdparm  и оказалось, она на быст сервере 158.43 MB/sec, а на медл. 200.08 MB/sec. Не понимаю.